# How to share application.properties among modules with maven for spring-boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have a maven project with sprint-boot services as below

```
--pom.xml
  --service1
    --pom.xml
    --src
      --main
        --resources
          --application.properties
  --service2
    --pom.xml
    --src
      --main
        --resources
          --application.properties
  --service3
    --pom.xml
    --src
      --main
        --resources
          --application.properties
```

all services will be deployed on an external tomcat server.

There are lots of common properties among "application.properties" files. Is there an elegant way share these common properties among services?

Comment: did you try make your application.properties as jar and share as a dependency in your service?

Comment: Many thanks. That should work

Comment: Is there a way that I can still use the common properties with @Value as local properties in application.properties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to do it in elegant way, i would suggest you to use ***Spring Cloud config*** for this.

This service from Spring helps you to Centralized any configuration for different services.

For More information:

1. https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/
2. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-configuration
3. http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/1.4.1.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html

Comment: Using spring cloud config is not a complete answer.  If you move application.properties to spring cloud config, it becomes visible to **all** projects using the same spring cloud config. Thus, you need to use a specific `spring.application.name`  (e.g., `myservices`) that has to be configured in each of the 3 services. I think a profile (e.g., `common`) needs to be defined and used when launching the 3 services, and the common properties should be in `myservices-common.properties` in the spring cloud config repo.